# Elastic net: how to tune for both lambda and alpha? Why is caret better than cv.glmnet?

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret, glmnet, elastic-net

I'm learning how to use R to fit Elastic Net models using the `glmnet` package. There appears to be a function, `cv.glmnet` that allows a user to determine the best value of $\lambda$, but still requires $\alpha$ to be manually set. For a given dataset, I would like to find both the optimal value for $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ for an elastic net model fitting this dataset.

Initially I decided to try running `cv.glmnet` multiple times for a set of possible $\alpha$ values (0, 0.1, ... 1). My idea was that if the folds were kept the same for each fit, then the best $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ would be used by the model with the best CV score out of the 11. However, my colleague tells me that this was incorrect, and recommended that I use `caret` instead.

From what I've read on here and other papers, the `caret` package has been recommended as a way to simultaneously tune both $\lambda$ and $\alpha$. The package requests users to submit a grid for both parameters and from what I can tell tries at least several permutations of $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ and converges to an optimal value for both.

What I don't understand is why this is seen as being superior to my "simple" attempt. Assuming that both the folds and the possible values of $\lambda$ & $\alpha$ are fixed, would there be any reason that my nested `cv.glmnet` method would perform worse than `caret`? Is my colleague concerned only by computation time & efficiency, or is there something statistically unsound about my method?